# Perform data assay with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data file with a fields separated by commas that I received from someone. I have to systematically go through each column to understand things like usual descriptive statistics:
-Min
-Max
-Mean
-25th percentile
-50th percentile
-75th percentile

or if it's text:
-number of distinct values

but also I need to find
-number of null or missing values
-number of zeroes

Sometimes the oddities of a feature mean something, i.e. contains information. And I might need to circle back with the client about oddities I find. Or if I'm going to replace values I have to make sure I'm not steamrolling over something recklessly.

So my question  is this: Is there a package in python that will find this for me without my presupposing the data type? And if it did exist, would pandas be a good home for it?

I see that pandas makes it easy peezy to replace values but in the beginning I just want to look.

Comment: If you load a csv into a `pandas DataFrame`, you can easily create a function that will take a column and output what you want if it's basic mathematic things like percentiles, mins etc. And I am not sure what you mean for text. But I don't think you will find a package because what you need is not that complicated unless you are underselling the issue.

Comment: You can call `df.describe()` on the DataFrame to get a description of each column.  It's not clear from your question exactly what you want beyond that.

Comment: @BrenBarn: That is true, and I almost mentioned it, but that wont give you the percentiles, will it?

Comment: @RyanSaxe: It does give the percentiles.

Comment: Oh, well I don't remember that. I used it once for mins and maxes for dealing with stocks and don't have pandas loaded on this computer so I couldn't check. My bad

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) method:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(randn(10, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
          A         B         C
0  1.389738 -0.205485 -0.775810
1 -1.166596 -0.898761 -1.805333
2 -1.016509 -0.816037  0.169265
3 -0.440860 -1.147164  1.558606
4  0.763012  1.068694 -0.711795
5  0.075961 -0.597715  0.699023
6  3.006095 -0.354879 -0.718440
7 -1.249588 -0.372235  1.611717
8  0.518770 -0.742766  1.956372
9  1.304080 -0.803262 -0.609970

In [3]: df.describe()
Out[3]:
               A          B          C
count  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000
mean    0.318410  -0.486961   0.137363
std     1.360633   0.616566   1.266616
min    -1.249588  -1.147164  -1.805333
25%    -0.872596  -0.812843  -0.716779
50%     0.297366  -0.670240  -0.220352
75%     1.168813  -0.359218   1.343710
max     3.006095   1.068694   1.956372
```

*It has a `percentile_width` argument, which defaults to 50.*